# Tried to use Array List with Methods and Constructor. Can this be optimized?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, constructor

I've been practicing my coding for a bit now on Codecademy, and I decided to play around with ArrayLists on my own. Codecademy only showed me how to use println to achieve what value I want to print to the console. Instead I thought, well what if I wanted to use constructors and methods? I came up with this after playing around a bit, but as I'm still a beginner if I could optimize this better for the same result I'd love to know how. Thanks so much for your time!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class List {
  //set variables to be used in constructor and custom method
  String itemValue;
  int itemIndex;

  //declare shoppingList array
  ArrayList<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<String>();
  {
    //set what is inside the shoppinglist array
    shoppingList = new ArrayList<String>();
    shoppingList.add("Pumpkin");
    shoppingList.add("Carving Kit");
    shoppingList.add("Halloween Decorations");
    shoppingList.add("Face Paint");
  }

  public List(String itemName) {
    //set the value of what we want to find our index for to itemValue
    itemValue = itemName;
  }

  public void getIndex() {
    //sets the index of itemValue to itemIndex then prints the name and index
    itemIndex = shoppingList.indexOf(itemValue);
    System.out.println("The index of " + itemValue + " is " + itemIndex + "!");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare shoppingIndex object
    List shoppingIndex = new List("Face Paint");
    //Calls get index to print our Item name and its index in shoppingList
    shoppingIndex.getIndex();
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a question that would fit better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com . Best of luck over there!

Comment: Thank you very much for this link, no idea this site existed! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid '//' comments, rely on readable code and javadoc

After java7

```
  ArrayList<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

becomes

```
  ArrayList<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
```

initializations like the `shoppingList` should be placed in constructor

`itemValue` should be private final

`itemIndex` can be converted to local variable in `getIndex`

`getIndex` the name suggests that it will return the index but its void, better return the index and let the user of the method decide what to do with it.